# content type field not printing

Tags: 7, nodes

In drupal 7, I defined a field for a custom content type and am trying to display its value via page.tpl.php.  Nothing is appearing in the rendered page.

Here's the relevant piece of page.tpl.php.  The field is 'field_mast".  Note that I added print $title just so I could be sure that this template is being used.  It is.

```
    <h1>Perinote&trade; <?php print $content['field_mast'] ?><br>
       <?php print $title ?> <br>Organize Your Way</h1>
```

My content type fields are:

```
Label  machine name field type            widget
Title  title        Node module element
mast   field_mast   Text                  Text field
Body   body         Long text and summary Text area with a summary
```

And for Manage Display, I have:

```
Field   Label        Format
Body    <Hidden>     Default
mast    Above        Default
```

Finally, for my actual content, I have:

```
Title: Notes contacts....
mast: User Guide
Body <p>This user guide...
Text format: Full HTML
```

Any ideas on what I need to do to get 'mast' to print?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<h1>Perinote&trade; <?php print render($content['field_mast']); ?><br>
```

or this one

```
<h1>Perinote&trade; <?php print render($content['field_mast']->value); ?><br>
```

I recommend you to download and install [devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module and write

```
<?php kpr ($content);?>
```

to see what `$content` contains. you can also call this function in `hook_preprocess_page` as well.

Comment: Hi.  I installed devel but I'm not sure if I've done it right.  After installation, "modules" showed three "development" modules.  I enabled "Devel".  Then, in "blocks", I saw "development" listed twice.  Not sure if that comes from Devel.  I placed both in the footer region of my page.  Now, when viewing a page, I see list of menu items.  Among them is "field info".  If I click on that, I get a popup of Fields, Instances, ... I can see "field_mast" in the list.  Not sure what to look for at this point.

Comment: I added kpr ($content) and it shows field_mast to have value NULL.  Not sure why.  It's defined for the page, as I show in my original post.

Comment: now write `kpr($page['content'])`

Comment: also in `template.php` and in `hook_preprocess_node(&$variables)`  write `kpr($fields)` to see if the field has value

Comment: thanks again for your suggestions.  I added kpr($page['content']) and got some output but I don't really know what to look for in the output.  I also added kpr($fields) but that didn't even produce an empty rectangle.  I experimented with hook_preprocess_node and hook_preprocess_page as well but am not sure which module to put it in.  I tried templates.php and got "already defined errors".  Any more ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: You can't use the fields name directly  in `page.tpl.php` by their name. In `hook_preprocess_page(&$variables)` write `kpr($variables)` and find the `field_mast` and assign its value to `$variables` array, like `$variables[mast] = $variables[...]...` then in `page.tpl.php` use `$mast`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22346/discussion-between-peri-hartman-and-drupalist).

Comment: didn't see you in chat so I'll go ahead and post.  Where do we put the hooks? I tried templates.php - is that where you intended? And which module? Isn't hook_* the generic form and I need a specific module, such as template_preprocess_page, etc?

Comment: Yes it is `template.php`. In this context `hook` `means your theme name. If you use `bartik`, then just write `bartik_preprocess_page(&$variables)`, If this function is already in `bartik` theme, append your code in to that function.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the additions to template.php.  Did that but nothing is appearing on the webpage for the two kpr functions.  I adding printing a header to be sure they are being called.  They are.